# How to prevent Windows from showing desktop when the pointer hover over the right bottom corner?

Tags: windows-10

I'm using Windows 10, and it happens that the mouse pointer comes near that corner and shows desktop distracting me from the work i'm doing. I want to disable it if available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Waiting an answer, I right clicked this corner and I found the option that disable it, I unchecked **Peek at desktop**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right click your taskbar at the bottom of your screen and select 'Properties'

This should appear:

---

[image]

---

From here, you would uncheck the box that states *"Use peek to preview the desktop when you move your mouse to the Show Desktop button at the end of the taskbar"*

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: No problem.  Already gave you a +1 for resolving it yourself.  Two different ways to achieve the same thing, so I figured it wouldn't hurt to leave this too :)